# Gem dependency in brew formula

Tags: rubygems, dependencies, homebrew

Is it possible to have a ruby gem dependency for a formula?

There is a paragraph about it in the doc, but no further explanation: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#specifying-gems-python-modules-go-projects-etc-as-dependencies

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm looking now, will update if I find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution via a combination of [this formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/cbda64c699e029697f8c0ee89052ffcfcdf589e6/Formula/mikutter.rb) and [this gem](https://github.com/midchildan/resona), which the first project seems to use co-incidently.

Long and short of it is, resource per gem, install to a directory, update your scripts `GEM_HOME` so it can find them:

```rb
class GemDependentProject < Formula

  #...cut

  resource 'aws-sdk' do
    url 'https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-2.6.29.gem'
    sha256 '686ecaf63713d7a123cdfb1d746cc660236b6c8c3ac0b4f12b56479fa0542f06'
  end

  def install
    prefix.install 'bin', 'lib'

    resources.each do |r|
      r.verify_download_integrity(r.fetch)
      system("gem", "install", r.cached_download, "--no-document",
             "--install-dir", "#{lib}/gem-dependent-project/vendor")
    end

    (bin/"gem-dependent-project-script").write(init_script)
  end

  def init_script
    <<-EOS.undent
    export GEM_HOME="#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/lib/gem-dependent-project/vendor"
    # Continue as normal...
    EOS
  end

    #... cut
end
```